# State of Dynamically Generated Radio Buttons

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm trying to pass a class only to the checked radio button in my component, but with my existing code all the radio buttons receive the class. Any advice?

```
export default function RadioGroup({options}){
  
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  
  return(
    <>
      {options.map(option => {
        return (
          <Radio
            radioID={option.id}
            radioName={name}
            radioLabel={option.label}
            radioClass={` ${isChecked ? "bg-blue" : ""}`}
            onChange={() => setIsChecked((prev) => !prev)}
          />
        )
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing Boolean in `setIsChecked`, you have to pass the `id` then you can add the `bg-blue` class on `id` base, as you can see the below code.

```
export default function RadioGroup({options}){
  
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(null);
  
  return(
    <>
      {options.map(option => {
        return (
          <Radio
            radioID={option.id}
            radioName={name}
            radioLabel={option.label}
            radioClass={` ${(isChecked === option.id) ? "bg-blue" : ""}`}
            onChange={() => setIsChecked(option.id)}
          />
        )
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: One issue is when `isChecked` is set to true in the story, the styling breaks and clicking on other radios in the group doesn't work right. Any ideas?